# Need help loading data with AJAX and a couple other things

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I need some help. I'm creating a Facebook application.

what I need to do is:
 1. grab the JSON data from a PHP page (the whole page is just JSON text, nothing else)
 2. take those items and put them into an array inside the javascript code
 3. load those links from array in the background while displaying their picture and "Loading..." text
 4. when each page is done loading, fetch the contents of `<div name="desc"></div>` and replace the "Loading..." text with it
 5. repeat these steps without refreshing the page as soon as every page as been loaded

there can be up to 25 pages in the array, but not always.

this is what the JSON data looks like:

```
[
   {
     "picture":"URL_TO_PICTURE",
     "link":"URL_TO_SITE"
   },
   {
     "picture":"URL_TO_PICTURE",
     "link":"URL_TO_SITE"
   },
   {
     "picture":"URL_TO_PICTURE",
     "link":"URL_TO_SITE"
   }
]
```

if someone could help me out with this, I would GREATLY appreciate it! I'm pretty stumped at the moment.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hace few different problems there.

---

1) Consume a REST WS, this can me achieved using JQuery Ajax Call. This is simple, check [this link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), There are some examples at the end of the page. Just set te type of your call (I supose this is a GET), content type of data submitted, and type of data expected and URL.

---

2) Put de received data into a JSon array, do this in the done function like the following

```
    .done(function(msg) {
       var msg = JSON.parse(msg);
       console.log("Data loaded successfully and parsed to JSon Array!!");
    }
```

---

3) For you "Loading" requeriment you can use "JQuery BlockUI" functions, check [this page](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/). To summ up, $.blockUI() to block you page, $.unblockUI() to unblock it. You can also customize the message and loadin gif. If I understand you well you wanna display this images while the screen is locked and when you're done, unlock.

```
   $.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img id="imgIdInBlock" src="busy.gif" />Loading...</h1>' });
```

If i'm right you need to block the screen before the ajax call, show the images and finnally unlock it. Put an image element inside the blockUI panel and update the src attribute with javascript like this

```
   function updateImg(data){        
      var imgInBlock = $("#imgIdInBlock");
      $(data).each(function(i,l){
        imgInBlock.setAttribute(data[i].picture);
        (sleep for some secs, search how to..);
      })
   }
```

This is the general idea, you may have to search some details but I think this is a good aproach.

Hope This Helps!!

Comment: thank you for the help. this helped me figure some of it out.

Answer (score 0):

Correct a little mistake

```
imgInBlock.setAttribute("src" , data[i].picture);
```

This will automatically load the image